# List of duplicate elements generator

Tags: java, list

Is there a java library that lets you generate a list of n elements of the same value.

Something like this:

```
List<T> getDuplicateElementList(int size, T value);
```

for example

```
Library.getDuplicateElementList(3, "?");
```

would return a 3 elements list, each element is equal to "?";

I need it to create placeholders for `in` clause prepared statement.

Comment: I would use a loop, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch would do the same.

Comment: I don't want to use a loop, because it is messes up the code. If a library had it like Apache or something, it would be cleaner to have in one line

Comment: Whatever you choose *does* use a loop. It will either be black-boxed into a function, or you'll create a loop explicitly.

Comment: @aliteralmind, agreed! but why write 3-4 lines of code if there's a way to do it in one.

Comment: Sometimes, it takes more time and effort to figure out that one line, than it does just to write the three. You've dedicated a whole question to it  ;)

Comment: Will pay off in the future ;)

Comment: Not if the future is today! (I don't even know what that means.  :)

Comment: @Is7aq Real Java code tends to have loops. The answers below use built-ins (and that's good too), but `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) al.add("abc");` is hardly `3-4` lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
List<String> list = Collections.nCopies(6, "abc");
```

As an example, that will give a list with 6 times `"abc"` as element.

Comment: I missed this one. That's better than my version.

Comment: Be aware that this returns an *immutable* list. `fill` edits an existing collection and is therefore mutable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the [fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill%28java.util.List,%20T%29) method of the Collections API.

For example:

```
Collections.fill(new ArrayList<>(100), ?);
```